# defined function used in for loop in python2.7

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Whether have some problem for my python scripts?

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools
import pandas as pd

def wego(weburl,annot):
    print 'Go Term: ', weburl.split('=')[-1]
    html=requests.get(weburl).text
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
    desc=r"desc=\".*\""
    print "GO leave 2 term:",(re.findall(desc,str(soup))[0].split('"')[1])
    pattern=r"Unigene.*A"
    idDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['GeneID']) #creates a new datafram
    idDF['GeneID'] = pd.Series(re.findall(pattern,str(soup))).unique()
    print "Total Go term is :",idDF.shape[0]
    old=pd.read_csv(annot,usecols=[0,7,8])
    getset=pd.merge(left=idDF,right=old,left_on=idDF.columns[0],\
    right_on=old.columns[0])
    updown=getset.groupby(getset.columns[1]).count()
    print updown
    print "Max P-value: ","{:.3e}".format(getset['P-value'].max())

with open("gourl.txt") as ur:
    d=[]
    for url in ur:
    we=wego(url,annot="file.csv")
    d.append(we)
```

my **gourl.txt** file is some url one line by one

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions=2
```

**my question is why the script can succeed when only one url in the  gourl.txt file and failed when more than one?**

The error follows:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
IndexErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-a852fe95d69c> in <module>()
  2     d=[]
  3     for url in ur:
----> 4         we=wego(url,annot="file.csv")
  5         d.append(we)
<ipython-input-4-9fdf25e75434> in wego(weburl, annot)
  5     soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
  6     desc=r"desc=\".*\""
----> 7     print "GO leave 2 term:",(re.findall(desc,str(soup))
 [0].split('"')[1])
  8     pattern=r"Unigene.*A"
  9     idDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['GeneID']) #creates a new dataframe 
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Have you checked `weburl` that gets passed into `requests.get()`? The other thing to check is the status code of the `requests.get()` response object.

Comment: I tried running your code and got `IndentationError: expected an indented block` on line 28. Are you sure this is the exact code you're running?

Comment: @Kevin yes, I have run successfully. The code 'wego=(url,annoy="file.csv")' haven't a problem.

Comment: @heyiamt  yes, I have checked it and I think the problem in for loop. Because it can succeed run when only one URL in gourl.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the stack trace you gave us you can see the answer. The last line says that you are trying to access a list element that does not exist ('out of range') at

```
print "GO leave 2 term:",(re.findall(desc,str(soup))[0].split('"')[1])
```

You make 2 list accesses in this line. One to get the first matched pattern and one to get the second term produced by `split('"')`.

So probably the second url does not have this pattern you expect it to have.

You can use something like this:

```
matches = re.findall(desc, str(soup))
tokens = []
if matches:
    tokens = matches[0].split('"')
if len(tokens) > 1:
    print("GO leave 2 term:", tokens[1])
```

Comment: Thanks! The script can run completed when I modify based on your suggestion. But only the finally URL can get a resulted when have more than one URL in gourl.txt file.

Comment: Check your assumption about what you expect to find, on all the urls you want to run the script on. Maybe you should use different patterns in your regexes. If you need more help, you will have to add sample input for which this script is not working

Comment: I have saved two html file about the URL that I want to parser in google drive( [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4N58_pNXx8hRk1SeHNvS0FjY2M)  and [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4N58_pNXx8hbDZ0MkZ2eVNYRUk) ).
And this file ([link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TMps1PmpMvxKFV2cdtdU8JD762_BtHC43UOAccsj9jY/edit?usp=sharing) ) is my output resultes and question when I run this python scripts.

Comment: @hope well they only reason I can see is that maybe requests is not actually getting the page for some reason. Otherwise it seems to be detecting all the descriptions.

Comment: yes, I also think the problem in for loop. But I don't knows how to modified and can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

So happy that the question has the solution.
The problem is \n in my **gourl.txt** file when read. I will show follows:

```
>>> with open("wegourl.txt") as ur:
...     d=[]
...     for url in ur:
...         print url
...         

http://stackoverflow.com/questions=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions=2
```

Undoubtedly, the empty line caused by the newline is not a licit URL and interrupted this scripts.
I can modify just  rid of \n when read file : `url=url.strip('\n')`